# How to Disable Tabs on Telerik RadTabStrips

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I have a RadTabStrip with a RadMultiPage associated with it. How do I (server-side), make it to where certain tabs are disabled, meaning the user cannot click on them?

```
<telerik:RadTabStrip ID="rtsSuggestion" runat="server" MultiPageID="rmpSuggestion"
        CausesValidation="false" SelectedIndex="0" OnTabClick="rtsSuggestion_TabClick">
        <Tabs>
            <telerik:RadTab TabIndex="1" Text="General" PostBack="false" Value="1" />
            <telerik:RadTab TabIndex="2" Text="Notes (0)" PostBack="false" Value="2" />
            <telerik:RadTab TabIndex="3" Text="Voting" Value="3" Visible='<%# !(DataItem is Telerik.Web.UI.GridInsertionObject) %>' PostBack="false" />
            <telerik:RadTab TabIndex="4" Text="Enhancements (0)" Value="4" PostBack="true" />
        </Tabs>
    </telerik:RadTabStrip>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
rtsSuggestion.Tabs[0].Enabled = false
```

where 0 denotes the index

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
function DisableItem()
{     
     var tabStrip = $find("<%= RadTabStrip1.ClientID
     %>");
     var tab = tabStrip.findTabByText("disable me");
     if(tab)
     {
         tabStrip.trackChanges();
         tab.disable();         
         tabStrip.commitChanges();
     }
 }
```